# Requesting approvals from different approvers for each document in a SharePoint library

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

We're trying to set up a document library where we can post documents and trigger an approval process, but where we define the approver or approvers for each document. In other words, every document is approved, but the sequence of approvers may be different for every document so we want to somehow set who approves each document and in what order when the document is posted.

I'm at a loss for how to set up the Flow to do this so any suggestions would be appreciated.

I tried to set up a flow in Power Automate using a field in the document library for approvers but it returns an error, I think because the process is triggered when I create the document and before I set that field.

Comment: Hi, you could share your current flow and the error details with us to check what's wrong with it. In power automate, there is a simple step "Start and wait for an approval" for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your error and a screenshot of your current setup?

Probably the easiest setup would be to create separate fields in the library for each approver and call them something like FirstApprover, SecondApprover and ThirdApprover.

For each Approver you could use their Email field of the library in the assigned to field of the Start and Wait for an approval action.

In this scenario I would use three separate Start and Wait for an approval actions.

[image]